# Cloudflare Error 502 Bad Gateway - Nginx - Laravel5

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, cloudflare, fail2ban

Lately, as soon as I logged into my site into dashboard, I kept getting this screen

[image]

How do I prevent this ?

I am using CloudFlare on top of my Nginx.

I used to use Fail2Ban, but I **disabled** it.

```
[nginx-req-limit]

enabled   = false
filter    = nginx-req-limit
action    = iptables-multiport[name=ReqLimit, port="http,https", protocol=tcp]
        jdoeddos
logpath   = /var/log/nginx/default-error.log
findtime  = 10
bantime   = 7200
maxretry  = 20
```

---

## Nginx

```
#limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name jdoe.com www.jdoe.com;
    root /home/forge/jdoe/public;



    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    
    

    location / {
        #limit_req zone=one burst=2 nodelay;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #limit_req zone=one burst=2 nodelay;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

  

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;



    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

---

Is there anything settings that I need to turn off ?

Comment: Have you tried another IP and restarting the webserver? also post your nginx config

Comment: I remember facing this issue where the main route works and the rest of the routs don't.
this issue is related to the .htaccess file in your public folder.

the easiest solution is to create a new laravel project take that projects .htaccess and make customizations based on your requirement.

If you need to make any change, otherwise just replace the file.
 :) keep a backup though, In case anything goes wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        #limit_req zone=one burst=2 nodelay;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

to

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Comment: What is the 2 lines that you added mean ? Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: this line 2, have for  page not found but, this line work for u ```fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; ```